# in python, is the function that its name is full-uppercase different from the common function?

Tags: python, django, database, cascade

in python, is the function that its name is full-uppercase different from the common function? just like "django.db.models.CASCADE":

```
def CASCADE(collector, field, sub_objs, using):
collector.collect(sub_objs, source=field.remote_field.model,
                  source_attr=field.name, nullable=field.null)
if field.null and not connections[using].features.can_defer_constraint_checks:
    collector.add_field_update(field, None, sub_objs)
```

Comment: No, the uppercase is typically used for *constants*. But in Python, functions can have all identifiers as name, and there is no distinction made by the interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, its the same. There are different naming conventions that you can use while naming a function. You can use all lower, all upper, lower case with underscore, etc. You can learn more about naming conventions [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).

Comment: how's that offensive? It happens, No need to apologize.